# How to mock appium driver(ios/android) using easymock?

Tags: unit-testing, appium, easymock

> Sample code which I tried to mock Appium IOS Driver, It gives Null >Pointer exception
>
> Initializing Driver and AndroidDriver object

```
Driver driver;
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> androidDriver;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
@Test
public void getLogAndroid_happyPath() throws Exception{
>Setting logs to mock return type

List<LogEntry> setLogs = new ArrayList<LogEntry>();
setLogs.add(new LogEntry(Level.ALL, 0, "logs"));
driver = new Driver();
```

> Mocking Android Driver with Nice Mock which can result in void 
>       enter code here>return types as well

```
androidDriver = EasyMock.createNiceMock(AndroidDriver.class);
driver.setAndroidDriver(androidDriver);
```

> EasyMock object call

```
EasyMock.expect(androidDriver.manage().logs().get(EasyMock.anyString()).getAll()).andReturn(setLogs);
EasyMock.replay(androidDriver);
try {
>Asserting mocked return type               

  assertTrue(driver.getLog("getLog",5000).contains(setLogs));       
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

>Verify EasyMock Object

EasyMock.verify(androidDriver);
EasyMock.reset(androidDriver);
}
```

Comment: Whats the idea behind mocking `AndroidDriver ` ?  I hardly image the case you have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `EasyMock.expect(androidDriver.manage().logs().get(EasyMock.anyString()).getAll())`.

Even if `androidDrive` is a mock, it won't cause `androidDriver.manage()` to return a mock. It will return null. So you probably have a NPE right now.

So you need something like (I'm using a more modern syntax as well):

```
androidDriver = niceMock(AndroidDriver.class);
what_is_returned_by_manage = mock(WhatIsReturnedByManage.class);
what_is_returned_by_logs = mock(WhatIsReturnedByLogs.class);
what_is_returned_by_get = mock(WhatIsReturnedByGet.class);
expect(androidDriver.manage()).andReturn(what_is_returned_by_manage);
expect(what_is_returned_by_manage.logs()).andReturn(what_is_returned_by_logs);
expect(what_is_returned_by_logs.get(anyString())).andReturn(what_is_returned_by_get);
expect(what_is_returned_by_get.getAll()).andReturn(setLogs);
```

But actually I would never ever code that. I would add a `getAllLogs` on `what_is_returned_by_manage` or something like that.